# JQGrid PHP subgrid level 2 is not rendering

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I searched here, but couldn't find solution to my problem.

I was trying to use the example code, Simple Subgrid worked fine. However, Subgrid 2 Level is not working.

grid.php contains:

`$grid->setSubGridGrid("subgrid.php");`

when I try to have the following code in subgrid.php

```
$grid->querySubGrid(array(&$rowid));
```

I get output like

```
{"rows":[{"stockNumber":"LOT1","stock":"5","expiration":"2013-01-01"}]}
```

Which means data passing is okay. However, when I try to use the following

```
$subtable = $subtable."_t";
$pager = $subtable."_p";
$grid->renderGrid($subtable,$pager, true, null, array(&$rowid), true,true);
```

it's showing empty grid!

Answer (score 0):

just set a primary key..

$grid->setPrimaryKeyId('CustomerID');